# Video autoplay for iOS not working in app

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working with the Ionic-Framework and I am using the Videogular plugin to play videos. But when I emulate it on the iOS it does not autoplay, while it does on desktop.

My HTML:

```
<videogular vg-width="config.width" 
vg-height="config.height" 
vg-theme="config.theme.url" 
vg-autoplay="config.autoPlay" 
vg-stretch="config.stretch.value" 
vg-responsive="config.responsive">
<video class='videoPlayer' controls preload='none'>
    <source src='assets/videos/level1.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    <source src='assets/videos/level1.ogv' type='video/ogg'>
</video>

<vg-overlay-play>Test</vg-overlay-play>
</videogular>
```

Modules:

```
angular.module('starter', [
                        'ionic', 
                        'starter.controllers', 
                        'starter.services',
                        "com.2fdevs.videogular",
                        "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
                        "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
                        "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.buffering",
                        "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster"
                        ])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
   // for form inputs)
});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use vg-autoplay="true" in videogular tag:

```
<videogular vg-autoplay="true">
```

Full Example:

```
<div class="videogular-container">
    <videogular vg-player-ready="onPlayerReady()" vg-complete="onCompleteVideo()" vg-theme="config.theme.url" vg-autoplay="true">
        <vg-video vg-src="config.sources" vg-tracks="config.tracks" vg-preload="config.preload"></vg-video>

        <vg-controls vg-autohide="config.plugins.controls.autoHide" vg-autohide-time="config.plugins.controls.autoHideTime">
            <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
            <vg-timedisplay>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-timedisplay>
            <vg-scrubBar>
                <vg-scrubbarcurrenttime></vg-scrubbarcurrenttime>
            </vg-scrubBar>
            <vg-timedisplay>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-timedisplay>
            <vg-volume>
                <vg-mutebutton></vg-mutebutton>
                <vg-volumebar></vg-volumebar>
            </vg-volume>
            <vg-fullscreenButton></vg-fullscreenButton>
        </vg-controls>

        <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
        <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
        <vg-poster-image vg-url='config.plugins.poster'></vg-poster-image>
        <div class="my-logo-layer" ng-show="API.currentState != 'play'">
            <img src="http://www.videogular.com/img/videogular.png">
        </div>
    </videogular>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't autoplay on mobile devices, it is disabled by default by the OS.

Comment: Then how does facebook do it

Comment: At any moment you must tap/click at anywhere and they take that event to play the video. This is a documented specification on almost all browsers: you can't autoplay videos to avoid bandwidth consumption, it must be the user who must allow the download.

Comment: Well I somehow managed to play it I don't know what exactly it was because I did several things but adding autoplay="autoplay" was the last thing I tried

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work but I don't exactly know how it worked. The last thing I tried was put autoplay="autoplay" in.

```
<videogular id="intro-video" vg-width="config.width" 
 vg-height="config.height" 
 vg-theme="config.theme.url" 
 vg-autoplay="config.autoPlay" 
 vg-stretch="config.stretch.value" 
 vg-responsive="true">
 <video class='videoPlayer' autoplay='autoplay' webkit-playsinline>
    <source src='assets/videos/level1.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    <source src='assets/videos/level1.ogv' type='video/ogg'>
 </video>
</videogular>
```